# Use $emit inside an click function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get input values in an editSwatch Vue method which has a click function to collect them when altered. In this I get an error that $emit is not a function, and when I try to put them in the main method, it is not getting the values. The original methods are getName and setbgColor in the main methods block, I am trying to use them inside this function to get values specific to the item being edited. Code is below:

```js
// Copy individual swatch to main div for re-editing
editSwatch() {
    let mainDiv = document.getElementById('bodybg');
    let smallDiv = document.querySelector("#bg-gradient > .bg-gradient");
    document.querySelector('#bg-gradient > .bg-gradient').setAttribute("id", "gradient");
    mainDiv.style.backgroundImage = smallDiv.style.backgroundImage;
    let pubBtn = document.getElementById('pubBtn');
    pubBtn.style.display = "none";
    Vue.swal('Reset Values and Save The Edit');
    document.getElementById('saveBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Get/Set bg and gradient values
        let bg = document.getElementById('bodybg');
        smallDiv = document.querySelector('#bg-gradient > #gradient');
        let textDiv = document.querySelector('#bg-gradient > #info');
        smallDiv.style.backgroundImage = bg.style.backgroundImage;
        textDiv.innerHTML = "";
        //textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${name}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
        Vue.swal('Swatch Edited!');
    });
}
```

and the original $emit methods are

```
 this.$emit('input', {
  value1: +this.value1,
  value2: +this.value2,
  value3: +this.value3
 });
```

But cant seem to use them in above, I need to get the values which are specific to the swatch being edited.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `click` handler has no bound context. Use an arrow function instead so that `this` is the Vue instance. However, you should avoid DOM manipulation in Vue, as those changes would be wiped away if the component is re-rendered.

Comment: Seems to be the only way to do it, as it is to handle/edit the one clicked swatch in a row of swaches, collect the new values then put back where it was. have nearly done that but cant get these values, new name and new colors, for this specific action. Otherwise, when swatch is first created, they are collected globally in the methods, example getName() {
      // Get the name value
      this.$emit('input', {
      value3: +this.value3
      });
      return this.value3;
   },

Comment: I've changed those global methods now, so maybe I can use them in this function   // Get the name value
    getName() {
      this.$emit('input', {
      value3: +this.value3
      });
      return this.value3;
   },
    // Get bg gradient values
    getbgColor() {
      this.$emit('input', {
      value1: +this.value1,
      value2: +this.value2,
      });
      return this.value1, this.value2;
    },

Comment: let hexValues = `${this.value1}, ${this.value2}`;
let name = (`${this.value3}`);
console.log(name);
console.log(hexValues);  These are logging undefined and using this.getbgColor() shows as not a function, which is true, its an $emit

Comment: Solved it with a combination of these comments Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a combination of comments below, changed the global getters/ $emits to return the values:

```
 // Get the name value
    getName() {
      this.$emit('input', {
      value3: +this.value3
      });
      return this.value3;
   },
    // Get bg gradient values
    getbgColor() {
      this.$emit('input', {
      value1: +this.value1,
      value2: +this.value2,
      });
      return this.value1, this.value2;
    },
```

Then used arrow function on click handler to make it a Vue instance, and got the values correctly.

```
document.getElementById('saveBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
let hexValues = `${this.value1}, ${this.value2}`;
let name = (`${this.value3}`);
console.log(name);
console.log(hexValues);
}
```

Thanks